# Appending inputs right after one another in correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my problem is I have 2 anchors one called Add Spell one called Add General Change and I want general change inputs to append right after my general champion name input one by one and right now if you add any spells and then add general change it will append after that spell.

Here is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e6y5903f/ and also on the webss http://89.69.172.125/cms2.0/

Most important bits of code

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click','a.AddGeneralChange', function(){
        $(this).parent().children().last().after(
           '<div class="GeneralChange">\
                <textarea type="text" size="20" name="GeneralChangeDescription['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]" placeholder="Enter General Change Description" />\
                <select name="GeneralChange['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]">\
                   <option value="buff">Buff</option>\
                   <option value="nerf">Nerf</option>\
                   <option value="new">New</option>\
                   <option value="change">Change</option>\
                   <option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>\
                </select>\
                <a href="#" class="RemoveGeneralChange">Remove General Change</a>\
            </div>');
    });
```

The function above is the one that is giving me trouble it is $(this).parent().children().last().after( part I probably have to be more specyfic.

```
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.RemoveGeneralChange',function(){
        $(this).closest('.GeneralChange').remove();
    });
```

There is one more minor issue which you can test out on the website every champion has a dropdown if you have 2 champions and you will delete the first one dropdown won't show up on the last one on the site but if you will add one more it will start working again that's bizzare.

Update HTML

```
<a href="#" id="AddChampion">Add Champion</a>
<form name="second_form" id="second_form" method="POST">
    <div id="ChampionInput">
        <div class="GeneralChanges">
        </div>
        <div class="Spells">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and what I've tried in jquery

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click','a.AddGeneralChange', function(){
        $(this).parent('.GeneralChanges').append(
           '<div class="GeneralChange">\
                <textarea type="text" size="20" name="GeneralChangeDescription['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]" placeholder="Enter General Change Description" />\
                <select name="GeneralChange['+$(this).parent('div').data('id')+'][]">\
                   <option value="buff">Buff</option>\
                   <option value="nerf">Nerf</option>\
                   <option value="new">New</option>\
                   <option value="change">Change</option>\
                   <option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>\
                </select>\
                <a href="#" class="RemoveGeneralChange">Remove General Change</a>\
            </div>');
    });
```

Comment: Have you considered using extra elements such as `<div class="list-changes">` and `<div class="list-spells"></div>` ? You could then target their children without running into unwanted elements.

Comment: I would probably have to make a lot of changes to rest of the code could i get example as an answer? Wouldn't I have to move </div> after adding each new field? so it would be at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution is to do this:

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click','a.AddGeneralChange', function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.GeneralChange').last().after(
```

This selects the last children of the parent (presumably `Champion`) having the class `GeneralChange` and adds a new element after it. Except this only works if there already is a `GeneralChange` element present. Since we start with none, we can't add any. We can fix it like this:

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click','a.AddGeneralChange', function(){
    var elem = $(this).parent().children('.GeneralChange');
    if(elem.length == 0) {
        elem = $(this).parent().children();
    }
    elem.last().after(
```

But the mix of `Spell` and `GeneralChange` is pretty bad form and could lead to more annoyances regarding DOM manipulation. It also requires more logic to keep the order of elements.

A little restructuration is in order. We go from this:

```
<div class="Champion">
  <div class="Spell"></div>
  <div class="GeneralChange"></div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="Champion">
    <div class="Spells">
        <div class="Spell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="GeneralChanges">
        <div class="GeneralChange"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, instead of targeting the last children of a specific class, we target the container in which they are supposed to go:

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click','a.AddGeneralChange', function(){
    $(this).parent().children('.GeneralChanges').first().append(
```

Alternative code

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click','a.AddGeneralChange', function(){
    $(this).siblings('.GeneralChanges').first().append(
```

Comment: I really like the idea with one more div to keep them together but how do I add div that closing of Spells would have to dynamically change after adding each spell

Comment: You don't need to move tags around. When you use `append()` the code is inserted inside the element right at the end.

Comment: You need to add the divs to every champion after "Add Spell Add General Change".

Comment: alright I did that now how do I target that div since it's now a sibling $(this).sibling('.GeneralChanges').append( this doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Higeath I can't tell the difference. I'm not as familiar as you about how it's supposed to behave.